# How to remove the cover on a HP Pavilion 15-b055ca laptop?

Tags: laptop-repair, hp-pavilion, ultrabook

[I found the official HP instructions for this laptop on how to change the RAM but they're incorrect.](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00820047&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&cc=ca&dlc=en&lc=en&product=5328771) There are no "easy access" panels on the back of a 15-b055ca laptop.

A 15-b055ca laptop has 10 screws, two of which are labeled "keyboard" (they show the icon of a keyboard), and what seems to be a never ending number of plastic snap on/snap off latches.

I have managed to get the cover mostly off, but it's still stuck pretty good around the "busy" part of the case. (Where the power cable, usb ports, and card reader reside).

I have gone as far as removing the rubber pads on the bottom of the laptop to see if I haven't missed any screws there.

If anybody has any tips for removing this laptop's cover I would greatly appreciate them.

EDIT: Problem solved. The user manual was next to impossible to find but here it is: http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03550055.pdf

Comment: Are you able to post a picture?

Comment: I was able to find the user manual online here, they have great pics and I now have an SSD in my new laptop: http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03550055.pdf

Comment: you may want to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply search on hp.com for the product "15-b055ca" to find the pdf version of the maintenance manual: http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03550055.pdf